# package in R for BMA of a logistic model?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, forecasting, bayes

I am trying to perform analysis similar to Gerlach et al. (2002). it involves predicting the posterior probability of a particular binary outcome using the previous 5 observations. I was just wondering which package in R would be best to use for this.

I was also interested in how one could manipulate the arguments in the relevant functions to specify a prior that is a fixed value, depending on the range of the previous posterior probability. thanks.

Comment: please give a complete reference. ... I'm guessing you mean this one? Gerlach R, Bird R and Hall A (2002) 'Bayesian variable selection in logistic regression: predicting company earnings direction', *Australian & NZ Journal of Statistics*, vol.2, pp. 155-168

Comment: If your prior for some parameter is a constant value (i.e. if the variance is zero), you're saying there's *no* chance it's anything else. In that case, won't the posterior simply be the same fixed value?

Comment: You could use bic.glm in library(BMA). Take a look at this http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BMA/BMA.pdf and the examples therein.